# AWS Lex and Facebook Messenger Integration Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-messenger-bot, amazon-lex

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to get an AWS Lex based chatbot integrated with Facebook.

As far as I can tell, everything is set up correctly.

When I send a message to my page in Facebook, I don't get a reply. However, the analytics in my app shows that the app is getting messages, so I know the message is making it from the page to the app.

When I try to hit the AWS Lex Webhook directly using POSTMAN, the webhook responds to literally everything I sent to it with a blank HTTP 200 OK response.

The lambda function that is tied to the AWS Lex chatbot is not getting invoked as a result of the messages from Facebook because no logs are getting generated and cloudwatch doesn't show an attempts to run the lambda function.

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE : I ended up engineering around this by bypassing the Facebook channel capability inside AWS Lex and using Lambda instead. I deployed a passthrough API which calls a lambda function and then interacts with AWS Lex via Boto3/Python.  In theory this is all supposed to be taken care of from inside AWS Lex with the Facebook channel integration, but I wasn't able to get it to work so I just built around it.

Comment: Must be something with the set up, or your Lambda response. Can't really guess without seeing those. So you'll need to include screenshots of your Lex Console (specifically the  "Lambda initialization and validation" and "Fulfillment" sections)....also your response code in Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Verify Amazon lex is properly configured with facebook messenger .
    Check : Page access token 
            Verification token
            App ID
Check if your webhook is subscribed to page you are messaging on.
Check if your facebook user is added as tester/admin/developer
Check if your latest version of BOt is published on intended alias.
Also while configuring webhook tick necessary options : messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries, message_reads, messaging_payments

This should resolve your head ache. If not please reply